# When link building using the "guestography" technique, do I need to write a unique introduction to the content for each site?

Tags: seo, link-building, guest-blogging

I am planning to do link buliding using the Guestoghraphy technique discussed in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LfXH6WPUkKc) by Brian Dean.  I figured out pretty much how to do it based on the video.

However, he once said that before we offer to post info graphic to other niche related blogger we need to white an introduction to the info graphic for them to post with it. Many of them don't want to write an introduction. Do I need to deliver the same introduction to all bloggers or different & unique introduction to each of them?

Answer (score 1):

Step 4 of that technique is offering unique content.   From the video transcript that you linked to:

> Here's another twist that makes guestographics so powerful.
>   Instead of simply showing your infographic to someone
>   and hoping that they share it,
>   you sweeten the deal with a little bribe.
>   Don't worry, this bribe is totally above board.
>   So, what's the bribe I'm talking about?
>   A unique introduction to go along with the infographic.
>
> You see, when someone wants to share
>   your infographic on their site,
>   there's a huge barrier that usually stops them.
>   What is it?
>   The fact that they have to write
>   a unique introduction to go along with it.
>   After all, no reputable blogger is going to take
>   your infographic, slap it on their site and call it a day.
>   Their readers expect unique content.
>
> That's why you offer people that show interest
>   in your infographic a unique introduction.
>   Here's a script to send them.
>
> > Here you go name, let me know if you ever want to share
> >     the infographic on your site, I'll be happy to write
> >     a unique introduction to go along with it.
> >     Thanks, your name.
>
> And when they get back to you saying sure,
>   I'd love a unique introduction,
>   like this email that Perrin received,
>   whip up a high quality 200-300 word introduction.

So from the video that you linked, you absolutely need to be prepared to write unique content for each and every blog if you want to use this technique.